# Why do some psql lines have (# or '# after the database name?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm using psql in the command line on a Mac. Usually, when I type a command, the opening line reads `database_name=#`. I terminate the command with a `;` and that works nicely.

Sometimes when I write a command (which has been copied and pasted from a textbook I'm working through) I end up with the opening line being one of the following:

```
postgis_in_action(#

postgis_in_action'#
```

What do the `(` and `'` mean please? And how do I escape them to get back to 'normal'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you missing the closing braces or the apostrophe mark.

Normal one :

```
postgres=# select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('test'));                                                                                                                 
pg_size_pretty
----------------
8192 bytes
(1 row)
```

Missed braces/apostrophe:

```
postgres=# select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('test')                                                                                                                   
postgres(# );
pg_size_pretty
----------------
8192 bytes
(1 row)

postgres=# select count(*) from test where name = 'vignesh
postgres'# ';
count
-------
10
(1 row)
```

Valid query with no semi-colon will have hyphen:

```
postgres=# select count(*) from test where name = 'vignesh'
postgres-# ;
count
-------
100
(1 row)
```

Just cancel that query by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. Since that query is cancelled and not ran, pressing up arrow will not bring that up, as it will not be available in the history.

Answer (score 1):

When ever you type a query which is multi line and have some starting and ending brackets e.g ( ) then opening line will change to let user know that he has started a bracket that need to be closed.

see the below example:

```
    node1=# select
node1-# *
node1-# from
node1-# dept
node1-# where
node1-# deptno=
node1-# 1 and loc in
node1-# (
node1(# 'isb'
node1(# )
node1-# ;
 deptno | dname | loc 
--------+-------+-----
(0 rows)

node1=#
```

And if user somehow forget to close the brackets then opening line will show database_name(#

Even a single line query which has some brackets missing result in same opening line.

> node1=# select * from dept where deptno=1 and loc in ('isb';
>
> node1(#

To make the opening line normal you have to complete the query or just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> keys.

Answer (score 1):

The command you are entering was, as of the last time you hit "return", in the middle of either a parenthesized construct, or a `'` string.  It is waiting for you to close them.  It is going to ignore any normally-command-ending `;` characters it sees until you close out those constructs.

If your command is correct so far, then you just need to finish writing it.

If you want to abandon this command because you were supposed to close your constructs a few lines ago, and closing them now is the wrong thing to do, then you can hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, or in the case of `(`, you can type `\r` on a line by itself.  In the case of `'`, you would need to close it before using `\r`, because '\r' is legal content inside a string so it can't escape you out of the string.

Also, you can edit your command-so-far by typing `\e` on a line by itself.  But again, when in `'` you need to close the quote first, otherwise \e just becomes part of the string.